# NHibernate gets stuck after reading first record in foreach loop but brings back all records code below

Tags: c#, nhibernate, foreach

Below is the code i'm testing out trying to learn NHibernate because I found out I can't use EntityFramework with my current Unity 3d project, because Unity 3d isn't on the latest release of MonoDev that supports .Net 4

Anyways, I'm trying to retrieve following records I know there are 1306 records in the database.  When I debug I see that NHibernate has indeed retrieved 1306 records, but whenever I go into the foreach loop and expecting all 1306 records be dumped to the console I only see the first record in the database in the console as read.  It's like if it's getting hung up somewhere or possibly a network related issue since i'm using a database on my windows azure account

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
            {
                x.ConnectionString = "Server=tcp:xd2mistohd.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MegaMillionsDB;User ID=hpkmtgservice@xd2mistohd;Password={removed for obvious reasons};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;";
                x.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();
                x.Dialect<MsSql2012Dialect>();
            });
            cfg.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

            using(var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
            using(var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                //perform db logic
                var numbers = session.CreateCriteria<Number>().List<Number>();
                foreach(var number in numbers)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}", number.FirstRow, number.SecondRow, number.ThirdRow, number.FourthRow, number.FifthRow, number.MegaBall);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                tx.Commit();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press {enter} to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Please help, how can i fix my current issue to retrieve all records and loop through the foreach loop and get the results I'm expected?

Thanks,

Comment: nope it doesn't need to be there at all

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this fixed by calling the createcriteria

```
var numbers = session.CreateCriteria<Number>().List<Number>().ToList();
```